# Why Yup string validation doesn't throw error when it's an object?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I made an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/0xvk63rwl0) to show what is going on (I forked the first google search of "formik example").

I'm using [`react-select`](https://react-select.com), and it stores in the state a object with `value` and `label` properties.

I'm validating the Formik form with `Yup.string().required()` but it doesn't show any errors. Why it doesn't show any errors? Is this intentional or it's a bug? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Yup's documentation:

> By default, the cast logic of string is to call toString on the value if it exists. empty values are not coerced (use ensure() to coerce empty values to empty strings).

In other words it calls `toString()` on the select result which will be `"[object Object]"` (i.e. it is a string). You can fix it by using `strict()` ([documentation here](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedstrictisstrict-boolean--false-schema)):

```
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
  select: Yup.string()
    .strict(true)
    .required(" select Required")
})}
```

Of course then your select input will fail validation so you need to change it to something like this:

```
<Select
  options={options}
  value={options.find(({ label }) => label === values.select)}
  onChange={value => setFieldValue("select", value.label)}
  onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("select")}
/>
```